# PHP explode string, concat with search url and echo it

Tags: php

I have names of actors in variable `$actor`

Example:

```
Actor One, Actor Two,Someone
```

I need to split the string per person. I figured I'd use explode to get something like this:

```
[0] => Actor One
[1] => Actor Two
[2] => Someone
```

Then I need to build search links in following format:

```
http://site.com/?s=Actor+One
http://site.com/?s=Actor+Two
http://site.com/?s=Someone
```

And finally echo it like this:

```
<a href='http://site.com/?s=Actor+One'>Actor One</a>, <a href='http://site.com/?s=Actor+Two'>Actor Two</a>, <a href='http://site.com/?s=Someone'>Someone</a>
```

I'm just totally lost in PHP syntax. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please remember to choose an answer as accepted if it solved your question.

Answer (score 2):

(this is homework, isn't it?)

Anyway:

```
// $actors is an array with the names
$actors = explode(',', $actor);

foreach ($actors as $name) {
  $e_name = urlencode($name);
  print "<a href=\"http://site.com/?s={$e_name}\">" . htmlentities($name) . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: You're not htmlentitying the HTML, and the element content should not be urlencoded!

Comment: Yes I do. Urlencode() is there. And why should I use htmlentities on a print?

Comment: Sorry, wrong way round. The link element text should **not** be encoded; but it rather HTML-entitified.

Comment: Not a homework, just editing a site for friend. Who has school now anyways?

Comment: It works well, but there's no comma between actors and from second query up it contains + even before actor's name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array('Actor One','Actor Two','Someone');
foreach($arr as $value){
 echo '<a href="http://site.com/?s='.rawurlencode($value).'">'.htmlentities($value).'</a>';
}
?>
```

**Oops** url encoding.. my bad!

Comment: You're neither urlencoding the GET parameter nor htmlentitying the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of steps to what you need to do:

1. `explode` the string into an array (as you did)
2. Create and echo the links with those urls
3. When the actor name goes into a url, remember to `rawurlencode` it
4. When it goes into HTML, remember to `htmlspecialchars` it

So the above can be translated into this code:

```
$actors = explode(',', $actor);

foreach($actors as $actor) {
    printf('<a href=\'http://site.com/?s=%s\'>%s</a>',
           rawurlencode($actor),
           htmlspecialchars($actor));
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: please help me improve the answer by leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to post a safe version that works independently of whether the array content has been maliciously prepared:

```
$cs = "UTF-8";
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", $cs);

/* ... */

foreach($actor as $name)
{
  print('<a href="http://site.com/?s=' . htmlentities(urlencode($name), ENT_QUOTES, $cs)
        . '">' . htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, $cs) . '</a>');
```

Probably best to include the encoding as well, after all your array could contain all sorts of characters.